# Prolog FibonacciSeries

Tags: prolog, fibonacci

We want to obtain the series of terms from m to n of the fibonacci sequence,
that is, the sum of all the terms from position m to n.

a) Do a FibonacciSeries(M,N,S) procedure add the terms from M
up to and including N and return the result in S.

[image]

Comment: B **is** N-2 not B = N-2.

Comment: Examples at e.g. https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Prolog

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.